# How can you set up scoped redirects for Sinatra apps

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a series of sinatra applications that are set up such that each is responsible for one thing.

Let's say I have two apps like this:

```
class Foo < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      'FOO!'
    end
end

class Zoo < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      'ZOO!'
    end

    get '/zoom' do
      # do things
      redirect '/'
    end
end
```

Now let's say I have my config.ru as such:
require './application'

```
run Rack::URLMap.new('/' => Foo.new, '/zoo' => Zoo.new)
```

The problem I'm running into is when I try to do the redirect in the `zoom` action I get sent off to the index action of `Foo` instead of `Zoo`.  Is there a clean way to do this such that my applications don't need to know how the routes are set up for the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use configurable redirects. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/2011/03/03/sinatra-1.2.0.html#configurable_redirects.

E.g.

```
class Zoo < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      'ZOO!'
    end

    get '/zoom' do
      # do things
      redirect to('/')
    end
end
```

Or alternatively, as mentioned in the link above, skip the to() call by enabling prefixed redirects in the Zoo app:

```
class Zoo < Sinatra::Base
    enable :prefixed_redirects
    ...
```

Comment: redirect to() was exactly what I was looking for.  It allows me to keep my routes localized and if I ever *really* need to I still have access to all the others in my app!